# How to make datastore keys mapreduce-friendly(-er)?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, mapreduce

Edit: See my answer. Problem was in our code. MR works fine, it may have a status reporting problem, but at least the input readers work fine.

I ran an experiment several times now and I am now sure that mapreduce (or DatastoreInputReader) has odd behavior. I suspect this might have something to do with key ranges and splitting them, but that is just my guess.

Anyway, here's the setup we have:

1. we have an NDB model called "AdGroup", when creating new entities
   of this model - we use the same id returned from AdWords (it's an
   integer), but we use it as string: `AdGroup(id=str(adgroupId))`
2. we have 1,163,871 of these entities in our datastore (that's what
   the "Datastore Admin" page tells us - I know it's not entirely
   accurate number, but we don't create/delete adgroups very often, so
   we can say for sure, that the number is 1.1 million or more).
3. mapreduce is started (from another pipeline) like this:

   ```
   yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
       job_name='AdGroup-process',
       mapper_spec='process.adgroup_mapper',
       reducer_spec='process.adgroup_reducer',
       input_reader_spec='mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
       mapper_params={
           'entity_kind': 'model.AdGroup',
           'shard_count': 120,
           'processing_rate': 500,
           'batch_size': 20,
       },
   )
   ```

So, I've tried to run this mapreduce several times today without changing anything in the code and without making changes to the datastore. Every time I ran it, mapper-calls counter had a different value ranging from 450,000 to 550,000.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but considering that I use the very basic DatastoreInputReader - mapper-calls should be equal to the number of entities. So it should be 1.1 million or more.

Note: the reason why I noticed this issue in the first place is because our marketing guys started complaining that "it's been 4 days after we added new adgroups and they still don't show up in your app!".

Right now, I can think of only one workaround - write all keys of all adgroups into a blobstore file (one per line) and then use BlobstoreLineInputReader. The writing to blob part would have to be written in a way that does not utilize DatastoreInputReader, of course. Should I go with this for now, or can you suggest something better?

Note: I have also tried using DatastoreKeyInputReader with the same code - the results were similar - mapper-calls were between 450,000 and 550,000.

So, finally questions. Is it important how you generate ids for your entities? Is it better to use `int` ids instead of `str` ids? In general, what can I do to make it easier for mapreduce to find all of my entities mapping them?

PS: I'm still in the process of experimenting with this, I might add more details later.

Comment: What happens if you use the Datastore Admin backup feature? Does it successfully back up all your entities? That uses the same code, so it would be interesting to know if it works.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Interesting point, is there an easy way to see how many entities were backed up? Or do I need to actually restore the backup to see it?

Comment: How long does the pipeline take to run? Did you try with a different number of shards? Which version of the mapreduce bundle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation we have found that the error was actually in our code. So, mapreduce actually works as expected (mapper is called for every single datastore entity).

Our code was calling some google services functions that were *sometimes* failing (the wonderful cryptic ApplicationError messages). Due to these failures, MR tasks were being retried. However, we have set a limit on taskqueue retries. MR did not detect nor report this in any way - MR was still showing "success" in the status page for all shards. That is why we thought that everything is fine with our code and that there is something wrong with the input reader.